# Why will `read "1" :: Maybe Int` type check?

Tags: haskell, option-type

I wonder why `read "1" :: Maybe Int` will type check and throw an exception in runtime.

Is it possible that `read` can ever return a `Maybe a`? That is what `Text.Read.readMaybe` is supposed to do.

```
Prelude> read "1" :: Maybe Int
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

Comment: Because it will parse `"Nothing"` and `"Just 1"`.

Comment: Consider [`readMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe), which instead does what you wanted, and is a total function, unlike `read`.

Comment: Thanks. 
I wonder if possible to have a constraint `NotMaybe a`, `readNotMaybe :: (Read a, NotMaybe a) => String -> a`, such that the `a` can't be a `Maybe a`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**In short**: you parse the textual representation of the **`Maybe a` type**, *not* `a` as a non-total function where `Nothing` is used to specify a parse failure.

Well `read` is usually the *opposite* of `show`. It will thus parse a representation of an object, that is *frequently* how you would write the object as a cascade of *data constructors* into an object.

Now `Maybe a` is a type of the `Show` family, given the elements it wraps are an instance of `Show` as well, something like:

```
instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) where
    show Nothing = "Nothing"
    show (Just x) = "Just "++ show x
```

(In reality it is a bit more complex, since it will also introduce brackets in case you wrap a `Just 1` in a `Just` for example).

So the opposite can be parsed as well. For example:

```
Prelude> read "Nothing" :: Maybe Int
Nothing
Prelude> read "Just 5" :: Maybe Int
Just 5
```

So a `Maybe a` as a type of `read` is not meant for a "*non-total*" function, but to parse the textual representation of a `Maybe a` type.

So it parses strings with a prefix `"Nothing"` and `"Just"` (and also can parse some such "expressions" with brackets).

Answer (score 10):

> I wonder why `read "1" :: Maybe Int` would type check

Because `"1"` has the type `String` and is thus acceptable as an argument to `read` and `Maybe Int` implements `Read` and is thus acceptable as a return type of `Read`.

> and throw an exception in runtime.

Because "1" is not a valid string representation of a `Maybe Int`.

> Is it possible that read can ever return a `Maybe a`?

Yes, for example `read "Just 42" :: Maybe Int` is `Just 42` and `read "Nothing" :: Maybe Int` is `Nothing`.

Basically any string that you might get out of `show x` where `x :: Maybe Int` can also be fed as an argument to `read` to get a `Maybe Int`.

Or more generally, any output of `show x` where `x :: T` and `T` is an instance of `Show` and `Read`, can probably be fed to `read` to get back a value of type `T` - though of course instances can be defined arbitrarily, so not every type that implements `Read` and `Show` necessarily adheres to that "contract".

Comment: I feel it is important to remind people that `Read` (and `Show`) have implicit contracts of displaying and parsing strings representing valid Haskell values.  If your purpose is more general parsing then you can often get better performance or richer output using a pretty printing or parsing library.  This often trips people up, for example we can parse digits much faster than `Read` does if we can reject `(    (((( 0x37843)))))`, which `read` can handle.